# Variables in PDO-parameters and -queries

Tags: php

I have multiple if and elseif-statements like this:

```
if ($str == "CARS") {
    $first = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table_CAR (id_CAR, anything) VALUES (:id_CAR, :anything) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_CAR = LAST_INSERT_ID(id_CAR)');
    $first->bindParam(':id_CAR', $null = null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
    $first->bindParam(':anything', $anything, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $first->execute();
}
else if ($str == "PLANES") {
    $first = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table_PLANES (id_PLANES, anything) VALUES (:id_PLANES, :anything) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_PLANES = LAST_INSERT_ID(id_PLANES)');
    $first->bindParam(':id_PLANES', $null = null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
    $first->bindParam(':anything', $anything, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $first->execute();
}
```

Now I would like to make a function of that, because there is also done the same thing. The only difference are the names. But how can I put these words (CAR and PLANES) into variables? My problems are, that these words are part of queries and parameters and they aren't always the same (CARS != CAR).

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_CAR = LAST_INSERT_ID(id_CAR)` ? why do you do that? This will obviously not work... What about using `INSERT IGNORE` instead?

Comment: @Sebas: Don't worry. That works great :-) (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). With INSERT IGNORE ´$db->lastInsertId();´ gives the value 0...

Comment: Ok, sorry, forgot about that. I always get tricked by the semantics. It's sort of weird that LAST_INSERT_ID in the insert statement is already set to the id of current query...

Answer (score 0):

You can always construct the sql query in a variable first:

```
function insert($table, $anything) {
    // check $table using a whitelist to prevent SQL injections!
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO table_' . $table . ' (anything) VALUES (:anything)';

    $first->bindParam(':anything', $anything, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $first->execute();
}
```

As you can see, I cleaned up your query a bit. There's no need to insert a NULL value for `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields as MySQL will insert the correct value for you.

Comment: @TheWolf: Could you please escape the table name before inserting it into the query? Somebody using this code without thinking could create a nice SQL injection vulnerability here.

Comment: @user3142695: What for? lxg: While you're generally correct, escaping table/column names using PDO is not the easiest thing to do. Actually, some form of whitelisting should be applied. I've added a comment in the code.